# How to switch between desktop and mobile versions of the site?

Tags: php, javascript, session, mobile, cookies

I'm currently using the following method to switch between mobile and desktop versions of a WordPress site with [WordPress Mobile Pack](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-mobile-pack/)

```
<a href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>/?wpmp_switcher=desktop" onclick="document.cookie='wpmp_switcher=desktop;path=/;';">Switch to desktop</a>
```

and

```
<a href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>/?wpmp_switcher=mobile" onclick="document.cookie='wpmp_switcher=mobile;path=/;';">Switch to mobile</a>
```

I uses a session cookie to determine which theme to be displayed.

However this method is unable to handle the following scenarios

Scenario 1:

1. User is using mobile web version
2. User clicks "switch to desktop" link
3. User is redirected to desktop version.
4. User types site name (example.com) on the browser

Scenario 2:

1. User is using mobile web version
2. User clicks "switch to desktop" link
3. User is redirected to desktop version.
4. User presses device/browser back button

In both scenarios I need to redirect the user to mobile version of site.

Comment: You should allow an override only if explicitly set in the URL. e.g. ?override=mobile or ?override=desktop

Comment: @jraede it is causing navigation issue in the pages that comes after home page, if i'm checking that url param, i need to include it in all links either in mobile theme or in desktop theme.

Comment: That's true. But that's the trade off. Unless you want to have javascript to detect when the user leaves your site and then remove the override value from the session or cookie, then you need to do it like this and persist the override query variable through all of your links. You could always add some javascript to check the current url for override=? and add that to each link in the DOM.